# MySql json reverse search

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a MySQL table with a column of type `json`. The values of this columns are `json array` not `json object`. I need to find records of this table that at least one value of their json column is substring of the given string/phrase.
Let's suppose the table is looks like this:

```
create table if not exists test(id int, col json);
insert into test values (1, '["ab", "cd"]');
insert into test values (2, '["ef", "gh", "ij"]');
insert into test values (3, '["xyz"]');
```

If the input string/phrase is "acf ghi z" the second column must be returned as the result, because "gh" is a substring of the input. I read a lot about `json_contains`, `json_extract`, `json_search` and even `json_overlaps` but couldn't manage to solve this problem.
What is the correct sql syntax to retrieve the related rows?

MySQL version is 8.0.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_table()` to extract the JSON array as rows in a table.  Then just filter:

```
select *
from test t cross join
     json_table(t.col, '$[*]' columns (str varchar(255) path '$')) j
where 'acf ghi z' like concat('%', j.str, '%');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec34c1f6a119d4c3069db4dd6b060531) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This query works pretty well in MySQL but when I run it with [MariaDB4j](https://github.com/vorburger/MariaDB4j) for unit testing, I get this error `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(t.col, '$[*]' columns (str varchar(255) path '$')) j
where 'acf ghi z' like concat('%''`. As far as I know the MariaDB4j is backward compatible with MySQL and the version  `2.4.0` is far enough from `json_table()` appearance in MySQL. How can I get rid of this error? Thanks.

Comment: @user2041057 . . . You should ask this as a new question.  This question is clearly about MySQL.

Comment: I've asked it in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361272/how-to-resolve-mariadb-compatibility-problem-with-mysql) and it seems that MariaDB and MariaDB4j don't support `json_table()`. Is it possible to rewrite the above query without `json_table()` to be compatible with MariaDB4j?